# ValueError: The truth value of a GeoDataFrame is ambiguous

Tags: python, geopandas

Having issues filtering some 'name' values. I want to groupby month and name, after that filter a specific value from column name 'ar street3' and make a trend of that.

this is the code i wrote below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
'name'  : ['ar street3', 'ar street 3', 'ba foo', 'br', ' oo', 'ke'],
'month' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
'score' : [2.0, 5., 8., 1., 2., 9.]})

{fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(11,7))
df.groupby(['month', 'name']).filter(lambda x: 'ar street3' in x,df).mean(['score']).unstack().plot(ax.ax)}
```

I get this type of error:

ValueError: The truth value of a GeoDataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Can somebody point me to the right direction ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `lambda x: 'ar' in x,merged2017` supposed to do? (a small reproducible example showing what kind of data you have + what you want to achieve would help)

Comment: Is the question clear now? lambda is supposed to filter out the values i specified above and make a trend of that.

Comment: The groupby `filter` method expects a function (that is called on each group) and returns a boolean value. But `lambda x: 'ar' in x,merged2017` returns a tuple? Further, in `lambda x: 'ar' in x`, x would be a DataFrame, so you are checking if 'ar' is a column of that subgroup DataFrame. Which is not what you want to do I suppose.

Comment: In general: maybe you want to filter  before doing any grouping? (like `df[df['name'] == 'ar street3']`)

Comment: thank you, i didn't k
now what the lambda did actually. I just filtered before grouping and it worked out.

Comment: I wanted to combine filter and grouby in one line of code, but for me it is  not so simple yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to combine filter and groupby in one line of code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name'  : ['ar street3', 'ar street3', 'ba foo', 'br', ' oo', 'ke'],
                   'month' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                   'score' : [2.0, 5., 8., 1., 2., 9.]})

tag = 'ar street3'
df = df.groupby(['month', 'name']).filter(lambda x: tag in x.name)

print(df)
```

output:

```
         name  month  score
0  ar street3      1    2.0
1  ar street3      2    5.0
```

if you want to add month condition:

```
tag = 'ar street3'; month = 1
df = df.groupby(['month', 'name']).filter(lambda x: tag in x.name and month == x.month)

         name  month  score
0  ar street3      1    2.0
```

if you want only month:

```
#i have adapted the sample
df = pd.DataFrame({'name'  : ['ar street3', 'ar street3', 'ba foo', 'br', ' oo', 'ke'],
               'month' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1],
               'score' : [2.0, 5., 8., 1., 2., 9.]})

month = 1
df = df.groupby(['month', 'name']).filter(lambda x: month == x.month)
```

output:

```
         name  month  score
0  ar street3      1    2.0
5          ke      1    9.0
```

Comment: Thank you, is it possible to add an argument to the filter for selecting a specific month ?

Comment: i have modified my answer to do that